# backup MacOS documents that are on icloud

Tags: macos, icloud, backup, versions

I have activated my mac documents and desktop syncing to icloud drive. Now I noticed that I can't find version history for my files anywhere, including on my Time Machine backup. Is there any practical way to back up these documents?
If not I will move all my documents to my dropbox. There I have version history for a year and the smart sync function allows me free up space on my local hard drive.